# Obtaining URL of iCloud Shared Folder

Tags: swift, icloud

I have an Swift app which imports custom documents from iCloud using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` giving me a list of files from which I can choose, invoking:

```
didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]).
```

I have a button in my ViewController which calls

```
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is all working well. But I would like to hide the button if no files are present in the iCloudDrive shared folder.

I would be grateful for advice on how to check for the presence of a file in the user’s iCloud shared folder. 
i.e. how to obtain the URL?

The URL appears to be:

```
www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/~ hexadecimal string ~/MyFile.xyz
```

I cannot find any way of getting the hex string to allow me to construct the URL for using with:

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:
```